# I/O Reads and Writes per process Unix/SunOS?

Tags: unix, solaris, io

Can `prstat` or something similar tell me how many reads/writes a process is doing similar to how Task Manager on Windows can show `I/O Reads`, `I/O Writes` and many other I/O columns per process?

I'm using SunOS 5.10, but feel free to post other Unix flavours too.

Answer (score 3):

For a modern Linux utility check out `iotop`. Unfortunately it requires Python >= 2.4 and Linux >= 2.6.20 so it won't be much help to you on Sun OS.

For SunOS 5.10 you can use DTrace. There's some scripts on this [Top Ten DTrace Scripts](http://prefetch.net/articles/solaris.dtracetopten.html) page that are an example of what you can do. Of course you can tune them to your liking. I don't know of anything that will give you a nice out-of-the box utility though.

Comment: Download the DTrace Toolkit (http://www.brendangregg.com/dtrace.html#DTraceToolkit). it contains a number of DTrace scripts relating to IO - iotop, iohog, iosnoop etc. That should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [`sar`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5165/sar-1.html) and see if it does what you're looking for.